# Powershell click login button issue

Tags: powershell

I have seen some topics on adding lines to click a login button in a powershell script but I cannot get mine to work.

Here is one of the versions of the script I have tried:

```
    $username = "xxxxx"
$password = "xxxxxx"


$ie = New-Object -ComObject "internetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Visible= $true
$Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByID("lalogin") | where-object {$_.className -eq "loginbtn"}

$ie.Navigate("http://192.168.0.250")
Sleep 1
$ie.document.getElementById("loginUserName").value= "$username"
$ie.document.getElementById("loginPassword").value= "$password"
Sleep 1
$Link.item().click()


$ie.Navigate2("http://172.16.40.250",0x1000)
```

But all I get is the login page with credentials filled in.  Looking at some examples from the previous topics I cannot find on the webpage information what I should be referencing in the script to have it be successful.  Here is the code for the page:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
    <script>
        document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='../css/base.css?version=" + new Date() + "' type='text/css' />");
        document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='../css/login.css?version=" + new Date() + "' type='text/css' />"); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="loginbg">
            <div class="language" style="display: none">
                <select id="LanguageSelect" name="LanguageSelect" class="width120" onChange="g_oLogin.changeFrameLanguage(this.value)"></select> 
            </div>
            <div class="login">
                <div class="height25 lineheight25">
                    <span class="displayinlineblock width110 fontwhite">
                        <label id="lausername" name="lausername"></label>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <input type="text" id="loginUserName" class="inputwidth" maxlength="16" />
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="height25 lineheight25">         
                    <span class="displayinlineblock width110 fontwhite">
                        <label id="lapassword" name="lapassword"></label>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <input type="Password" id="loginPassword" class="inputwidth" maxlength="16" />
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="displayinlineblock width110"></span>           
                    <span class="loginbtn" onClick="g_oLogin.doLogin()" onMouseMove="this.className='loginbtnon'" onMouseOut="this.className='loginbtn'">
                        <label id="lalogin" name="lalogin" class="cursorpointer"></label>
                    </span>         
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="footer">
            <label name="laCopyRight"></label>
        </div>-->
        <div><div id="main_plugin" class="plugin"></div></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../script/LAB.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $LAB
        .script("../script/global_config.js?version=" + new Date()).wait(function () {
            $LAB
            .script("../script/jquery-1.7.1.min.js").wait()
            .script("../script/jquery.cookie.js").wait()
            .script("../script/Translator.js?version=" + global_config.web_version).wait()
            .script("../script/common.js?version=" + global_config.web_version).wait()
            .script("../script/login.js?version=" + global_config.web_version).wait(function () {
                g_oLogin.initLogin();
            });     
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try changing `$Link.item().click()` to `$Link.click()`.

Comment: Still get this error....

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\mzerfas\documents\test.ps1:7 char:1
+ $Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByName("lalogin") | where-object {$_.ty ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: Try this - 
`$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | Where{$_.InnerText match 'lalogin'}`; `$link.Click()`

Comment: It is saying that 'match' is an unexpected token.  I tried changing that statement back to =, but I get the original error.

Comment: Sorry my bad! Forgot to add the `-` in match. Try this --> `$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | Where{$_.InnerText -match 'lalogin'}; $link.Click()`